# PDF layer different headers and footers

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am testing out different APIs for PDF creation from HTML.

I am now testing Pdflayer.
I need different headers and footers for different pages.

I did not find any examples of that in the documentation.
I do not think that the @page and named pages work in Pdflayer (as they do in Docraptor for example).

Did anybody maybe work with Pdflayer and can help me with this?

Thanks and regards,

Grega

Comment: pdflayer uses a browser-based open-source library, and what you're trying to do is impossible because none of the browsers fully support CSS Paged Media. You'll have to use a PDF-specific engine like Prince (which is what DocRaptor uses).

Comment: Thanks @jamespaden. Do you maybe now of any other engines or APIs that support Paged Media?

Comment: I work for DocRaptor, so a little biased there, but you might check out PDFreactor or AntennaXML. They probably have better support than the browsers-based tools.

Comment: Thank you. What I need is an API, so both of them are not suitable. So far DocRaptor is the only API I found that supports the @page directive and named pages. Are there any others APIs that would support this?

Comment: DocRaptor is the only API that supports CSS Paged Media, yes. Out of curiosity (I work for DocRaptor), why are you looking for a different solution?

Comment: @jamespaden DocRaptor is Great, but a little expensive, thy is why I wanted to see If there are any alternatives. I understand that your prices are a higher, because you also have to pay for the Prince license.